# Editing an NHibernate record via AJAX

Tags: c#, nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm having trouble figuring out how to edit an existing entity when posting it to my controller. When I save a new `Person`, it works just fine, because `Id` isn't set, so NHibernate views it as a new entity and attaches it to the session. However, when I try to edit an *existing* entity, the MVC model binder can't set the `Id`, even though the JSON being posted has it properly set. So even though it's an existing entity, NHibernate again sees it as a new one, and then throws an exception because I'm calling `.Update()` on an entity that's not in the database or session.

Here's the code I'm using (obviously Person has a lot more properties, I just left them off to keep the code short)

Person class:

```
public class Person
{
    public virtual int Id {get; private set;}
    //... other properties
}
```

The JSON being posted to my edit action

```
{"Id": 10}
```

And in the controller

```
public JsonResult EditPerson(Person person)
{
    Session.Update(person);
    return Json(new { success = true});
}
```

Comment: How do you map your id ? Is it primary key on your table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was always under the impression that you had to load the entity to get it into the session so that you could edit it.

so you would need code like

```
var entity = Session.Get<Entity>(entity.Id);

//make your changes
Session.Save(entity);
```

Comment: Yeah, that works just fine. Unfortunately it means that I have to duplicate all of my domain entities as view models, but if that's what I'm going to have to do, I guess it's not the end of the world. Seems pretty anti-DRY, but maybe that's my only option

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
public virtual int Id {get; protected set;}
```

NHibernate uses proxies to load and set the properties of your classes, if your setter is private (rather than public or protected) the proxy (which inherits from your mapped class) cannot access it and assign the value it loaded from the database.

Comment: I tried that, and the model binder still doesn't set the Id properly. I feel like maybe this is something new to MVC5? I've done the same thing many times before with no problem, but I've always used MVC4. It seems like I'm missing something really obvious... but what?

Comment: @Jedediah What's the mapping of your ID property? Is it marked as an identity?

Comment: #Liath, what you expect to have with protected set of Id?

Comment: @Liath also tried Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity(), which didn't solve the problem either.